# Flywheel regenerative braking - gearbox

Tags: rotational-dynamics

If you were to use a completely mechanical flywheel (i.e. no use of a motor-generator) to use in a regenerative braking system, would the gearbox be responsible for controlling the "charging" and "discharging" of the system?

My assumption is that the gear ratio would be the determining factor in whether the flywheel is taking in energy or returning it. My reasoning being;

*To avoid confusion, the gear ratios will be in the format of $a:b$, where $a$ is the rotations of the flywheel shaft and $b$ the rotations of the drive shaft.*

Rotational Kinetic Energy is proportional to $\omega^2$. Therefore, surely when "charging" the flywheel, you would want the gear ratio to be such that it would accelerate the flywheel, and therefore the gear ratio should be fairly high. Then, when discharging you would want the opposite to be true, so you would choose a low gear ratio, so the flywheel decelerates and the drive shaft is accelerated.

I guess the best option would be to have multiple gears, shifting from low to high gears as the vehicle decelerates and vice versa when accelerating, and I suppose the ideal option would be to use a continuously variable transmission if you were to get optimum efficiency.

Are my assumptions correct, or is this not how the flywheel would be "charged" and "discharged"?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in asserting the need for a variable gearbox to go between the drive wheels and the flywheel. This would allow you to tailor the ratios for both the charging and discharging cycles for peak performance in both operating modes: high for one, low for the other, or whatever the situation calls for.

You'd also need a clutch to "feather" the flywheel in and out of engagement, but you'd get that essentially for free with a manual transmission.

Also worth looking into would be some sort of continuously-variable transmission that would automatically "solve" for the optimum ratio, so you wouldn't need to goof with the gearshift while dynamically braking on a hilly road.